# lvresize reporting incorrect Logical Volume size

Tags: lvm, disk-usage

I've used `lvresize` to add 15 Gb to a Logical Volume whose size was 10 Gb, according to `df` (and our records). However, `lvresize` found the LV to be 20 Gb in size and therefore the resized LV was 35 Gb.

Why is that?

```
[root@host]# df -h /mydir
Filesystem                                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/myvg-mylv                                10G  7.0G  3.1G  70% /mydir

[root@host]# lvresize -r -L+15G /dev/mapper/myvg-mylv    
  Size of logical volume myvg/mylv changed from 20.00 GiB (5120 extents)
  to 35.00 GiB (8960 extents).
  Logical volume myvg/mylv successfully resized.
meta-data=/dev/mapper/myvg-mylv isize=256    agcount=20, agsize=131072 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=0        finobt=0 spinodes=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=2621440, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=0
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data blocks changed from 2621440 to 9175040

[root@host]# df -h /mydir
Filesystem                                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/myvg-mylv                                35G  7.0G   29G  20% /mydir
```

Comment: You’re showing the file system size before the `lvresize`, not the LV size. `/etc/lvm/archive` should contain VG metadata backups, which should allow you to find the real LV size before the last `lvresize` (and the commands which were used on the LV). Perhaps the LV was resized without resizing the file system...

Comment: You are correct.  Someone else added 10 Gb to the LV but forgot to resize it.  If you want to write up an answer for it I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[root@host]# df -h /mydir
Filesystem                                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/myvg-mylv                                10G  7.0G  3.1G  70% /mydir
```

shows the file system size, not the LV size. The LV could easily be 20G in size (as reported by `lvresize`); this would happen for instance if someone resized the LV but then didn’t resize the file system. Your `lvresize` command took care of that thanks to the `-r` option.

`/etc/lvm/archive` should contain VG metadata backups, which should allow you to find the real LV size before the last `lvresize` (and the commands which were used on the LV).